# SQL returns entries with multiple reference in an other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to retrieve each entry from the table "Component" which appears to be in more than one "Computer". When I perform :

```
select Component.Piece, NO_COMPUTER from Component cmp
inner join Computer cpt
on Component.Piece = cpt.Piece
where Piece like 'i7 9210'
```

I get a result of two lines which is correct (like my 'i7 9210' is actually in two computers)

However now when I try to do that for each entry using :

```
select Component.Piece, NO_COMPUTER from Component cmp
inner join Computer cpt
on Component.Piece = cpt.Piece
GROUP BY Component.Piece, NO_COMPUTER
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cpt.NO_COMPUTER) > 1`
```

I have nothing in return

I tried to remove the `DISTINCT` but I can't figure out what's wrong

Comment: If you are grouping by `NO_COMPUTER` why would you expect more than 1 distinct value of `NO_COMPUTER` in that group..? The only value that your discount count *can* return is `1` so of course looking for groups where that count is `> 1` is going to return 0 rows.

Comment: Because I tried to remove the `NO_COMPUTER` from the `GROUP BY` and I got `Column NO_COMPUTER is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`

Comment: I'm not sure you follow my point. Let's say you have a deck of 52 cards, put them into four piles of each suit. Now pick up the hearts and count how many different suits you have in that pile. Now pick up the spades, and count how many different suits you have in that pile. Do the same for the clubs and diamonds. The only answer you can get to each count is one. It is impossible for our pile of cards of one suit to have anything else other than one suit.

Comment: Yes this makes senses, now I have to figure out how to translate this into my SQL Query

Comment: If, you want to count the number of cards in each pile, rather than the different suits in each pile, you would get 13 not one. Presumably you should not be counting the distinct values.

Comment: Ok I finally understand your vision ! thank you

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, this is the query you wanted to write:

```
select t.piece, t.no_computer 
from component t
inner join computer r on r.piece = t.piece 
group by t.piece, t.no_computer
having count(*) > 1
```

This joins the two tables, groups by component (assuming that piece and no_computer can be used as a primary key), and filters on tuples that have more than one match.

However, I find that this kind of filtering logic would be better expressed with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.* 
from component t
where (select count(*) from computer r where r.piece = t.piece) > 1
```